# Can't pip install xlrd, connection times out

Tags: python, command-line, xlrd

When I try to install xlrd via

```
pip install xlrd
```

I get the error message that

```
Collecting xlrd
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03593510>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/xlrd/
```

This error message repeats a few times and then I manually exit.  How can I install xlrd?

Comment: Works for me, are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Yep, that was it

Comment: I think it might be better to add an answer here so that people can see how it was solved, rather than just a comment, but that's just my guess.